# Show a adjacent hidden div on mouseover the link

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML and Javascript. I just want to show the hidden one at a time only when mouseover a link. If the mouse is over the link "Drink", then show the hidden div below that link only and other hidden div must stay hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>
            Untitled Document
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {


// timer for hiding the div
var hideTimer;

// show the DIV on mouse over
$(".show_div").mouseover(function() {
    // forget any hiding events in timer
    clearTimeout( hideTimer );
    $(".hello").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$(".hello").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout( hideTimer );
    $(".hello").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

// set a timer to hide the DIV
$(".show_div").mouseout(function() {
    hideTimer = setTimeout( hideHello, 333 );
});

$(".hello").mouseout(function() {
    hideTimer = setTimeout( hideHello, 333 );
});

// hides the DIV
function hideHello() {
    $(".hello").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

                });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
<br/>



<table border="1" width="400">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a class="show_div" href="#">Drink</a>
    <div class="hello" style="visibility:hidden;z-index:999;position: absolute;background-color:#99CC67;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Coffee
            </li>
            <li>
                Tea
            </li>
            <li>
                Milk
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
<td><a class="show_div" href="#">Friuts</a>
    <div class="hello" style="visibility:hidden;z-index:999;position: absolute;background-color:#99CC67;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Banana
            </li>
            <li>
                Water Melon
            </li>
            <li>
                Lychee
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a class="show_div" href="#">Movies</a>
    <div class="hello" style="visibility:hidden;z-index:999;position: absolute;background-color:#99CC67;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Avatar
            </li>
            <li>
                Star War
            </li>
            <li>
                Titanic
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
<td><a class="show_div" href="#">Books</a>
    <div class="hello" style="visibility:hidden;z-index:999;position: absolute;background-color:#99CC67;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Novel
            </li>
            <li>
                History
            </li>
            <li>
                Design
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table> 

<br/>
    </body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's alternative to what you are trying to accomplish. Instead of sticking with this method, you can  use other method to get the same result.

See the sample below, which is originally from [scottonwriting](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/10/23/163368.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottOnWriting+%28Scott+on+Writing%29) , but I made the sample look like yours. This is the sample of using tooltip as suggested on [scottonwriting](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/10/23/163368.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottOnWriting+%28Scott+on+Writing%29)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>
            Untitled Document
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .skmTooltipHost { border-bottom: dotted 1px brown; } .skmTooltipContainer
            { padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom:
            3px; display: none; position: absolute; background-color: #ff9; border:
            solid 1px #333; width :300px; z-index: 999; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {


                $(".skmTooltipHost").hover(

                function() {
                    $(this).append('<div class="skmTooltipContainer">' + $(this).attr('tooltip') + '</div>');

                    $(this).find('.skmTooltipContainer').css("left", $(this).position().left + 20);
                    $(this).find('.skmTooltipContainer').css("top", $(this).position().top + $(this).height());
                    $(".skmTooltipContainer").fadeIn(10);
                },

                function() {
                    $(".skmTooltipContainer").fadeTo(10, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br/>
        <table border="1" width="400">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Header 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header 2
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <span tooltip="Choose your drink:&lt;div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Coffe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Tea&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a target=_blank href=http://www.w3schools.com&gt;Visit W3Schools.com!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
                        class="skmTooltipHost">
                            Drinks
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <span tooltip="Choose your fruit:&lt;div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Orange&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Banana&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a target=_blank href=http://www.w3schools.com&gt;Visit W3Schools.com!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
                        class="skmTooltipHost">
                            Fruit
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <span tooltip="Choose your movie:&lt;div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Avatar&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Titanic&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a target=_blank href=http://www.w3schools.com&gt;Visit W3Schools.com!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
                        class="skmTooltipHost">
                            Movie
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <span tooltip="Choose your book:&lt;div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;History&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Novel&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a target=_blank href=http://www.w3schools.com&gt;Visit W3Schools.com!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
                        class="skmTooltipHost">
                            Drink
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </body>

</html>
```

There's always an alternative. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try out the [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function if your markup ends up changing at all.

**Edit** - updated for mouse-over (got a better idea of what you're doing). keep in mind though, you should use display:none instead of visibility:hidden so that you can more easily control it's visibility with functions like hide/show, fadeIn,fadeOut, slideDown,slideUp..

**Edit again:** I finally understand what you want. You don't want the div to dis-appear when you mouse over IT (like a drop down menu would operate). Here the revised code.

Note, this uses the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin for jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a.show_div").hoverIntent({ // capture the link hover events
     over:  function() {
             var $sibling = $(this).siblings('div.hello').show(); // get the sibling div and show it
             $('div.hello').not($sibling).hide(); // hide the other divs
             $sibling.data('linkOver', true); // store the fact that the link triggered this
            },
     out: function() {   
            var $sibling = $(this).siblings('div.hello');
            $sibling.data('linkOver', false);
            if( $sibling.data('divOver') != true) { // only hide if the mouse isn't on the div
              $sibling.delay(200).fadeOut(500); // get the sibling div and hide it after .333 seconds
            }
          },
    timeout: 500   //time to fire the event - must be greater than div.hover's timeout                 
  });

 $("div.hello").hoverIntent({ //capture the div hover events
     over: function() {
             $(this).data('divOver', true); // store the fact we're over the div now
           },
     out:  function() {   
             var $div = $(this);
             $div.data('divOver', false);
             if( $div.data('linkOver') != true ) { // if we're not on the link
               $(this).delay(200).fadeOut(500);  // then hide the div
             }
           },
     timeout: 400
   });   
 });
```

The idea behind this is the fact we're over one of the other items needs to be tracked. If we're about to hide the div on the link-out, we need to make sure we're not currently on the div. The same goes for the div, making sure we're not on the link.

You can try this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2pLR/

I also updated your [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pbYzVPyw) entry.

Comment: I just replace my $(".show_div").mouseover(function() with yours. But nothing shows up when I mouse over any link.

Comment: because you're using visibility:hidden; in your markup - use display:none. I updated my answer to more suit what i think are your needs..

Comment: Dan, the hidden Divs wont show up at all when I replace your $("a.show_div").hover with $(".show_div").mouseover. Please help me check.

Comment: did you change `<div class="hello" style="visibility:hidden;` to ` <div class="hello" style="display:none;` ? - oh, and try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cHyME/

Comment: I tried your demo. There's a problem.. I can't hover over the Div, the moment the mouseout of the link the Div also gone. I want to be able to hover on the link also. Please check it.

Comment: well not the moment, .333 seconds after the moment. .333 seconds is NOT a lot of time (Got that from your question's sample code btw). Try it with more and you'll see it works as it's supposed to. http://jsfiddle.net/cHyME/1/

Comment: Dan, in the sample code, the Div stay visible always when mouseover it, it dissapear when mouseout of it and the link. I want the Div to stay visible when mouseover it and the link. Thank so much for the reply. Please check my question again.

Comment: are you saying you want the _other_ divs to hide when mouseover occurs on the link?

Comment: Yes, the other divs must stay hidden when mouseover the link and the div itself.

Comment: Updated answer to hide other divs but not the one you want to show. (which is what i had for an answer to start with, incidentally..)

Comment: Hi, Dan. I updated my sample code to include your updated answer. Please see it here http://pastebin.com/e3QWnueZ There's still a problem. I cannot do mouseover the div.

Comment: Ah - i get what you're after now. Like a menu drop down, where the div stays visible when it's moused-over. I've updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: Though I just noticed you've already marked the other answer as the correct one, so I see I was way off-base in my efforts. Sorry to mis-understand ya so greatly

Comment: I was so much busy with World Cup 2010...Thank you for your answer. Really appreciate this. I learn some things from your post also. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a.show_div').mouseover(function(){
  $('div.hello').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // hide all
  $(this).next('div.hello').css('visibility', 'visible'); // show this one
});
```

Also, consider using the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method if you want to show/hide the stuff when mouse enter/leaves them.

Comment: I tried replacing my $(".show_div").mouseover(function()  with yours. But there's problem when I mouse over the Div the other hidden Divs also show up. Can you point me out to fix that bug?

Comment: @Morron: That seems to be with your code where it starts with `$(".hello").mouseover(function()`, let me know if that is the case, try removing that and then see.

Comment: I removed $(".hello").mouseover(function() but I can't move over the Div now. The Div disappears when the mouseout of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.show_div').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).next('.hello').show(); 
   })
   $('.show_div').mouseout(function(){
       $(this).next('.hello').hide(); 
   })
})
```

You can also add some timers to auto hide.
Hope this gave you some inspiration.